# Can Java App Build in Intellij with jdk 17 works on tomcat running on jdk11

Tags: java, java-17

Can Java App Build in Intellij with jdk 17 works on tomcat running on jdk11.

Build Project using java 17 and deploy/run using java 11.

Comment: Possibly.  But why take the risk?  Build it on JDK11.

Comment: In principle it can with the right settings (you'll have to compile for Java 11) but you cannot use Java features that were added after Java 11 and you'll have to be careful to not use standard library classes that were added after Java 11. In other words, there's no benefit to using Java 17 in this case and you're making it difficult for yourself... if it has to run on Java 11, then it's best to use JDK 11 and avoid problems.